# Force method call order in Groovy DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl

I'm developing a small DSL in Groovy and I was wondering if is there any way to force an order in the method calls.

For example, this would be valid

```
SensorDSL.camera {
    take "picture" store_in "path" on {
        success "mySuccessCallback"
        cancel "myCancelCallback"
        error "myErrorCallback"
    }
}
```

but writing `store_in` before `take` method shouldn't be allowed.

Here is my current code.

```
class SensorDSL {   
    def static camera(@DelegatesTo(CameraHandler) Closure closure){
        CameraHandler delegate = new CameraHandler()
        def code = closure.rehydrate(delegate, null, null)
        code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        code()
    }
}

class CameraHandler {
    String mediaType
    String path

    CameraCallbackHandler callbackHandler

    public CameraHandler(){
        callbackHandler = new CameraCallbackHandler()
    }

    CameraHandler take(String mediaType) {
        if (!MediaType.values().collect{it.toString()}.contains(mediaType.toUpperCase())){
            throw new Exception("Only PICTURE or VIDEO can be taken")
        }
        this.mediaType = mediaType
        this
    }

    CameraHandler store_in(String path){
        this.path = path
        this
    }

    void on(@DelegatesTo(CameraCallbackHandler) Closure closure){
        def code = closure.rehydrate(callbackHandler, null, null)
        code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        code.call()
    }

    class CameraCallbackHandler {
        String successCallback
        String errorCallback
        String cancelCallback

        CameraCallbackHandler success(String methodName){
            this.successCallback = methodName
            this
        }

        CameraCallbackHandler cancel(String methodName){
            this.cancelCallback = methodName
            this
        }

        CameraCallbackHandler error(String methodName){
            this.errorCallback = methodName
            this
        }
    }
}
```

Also it would be great if there is any way to make a method call required without manual checking.

**Edit:** I've found a way that seems to work. If the return of the method is a map of closures, you can call the methods in the given order. For example:

```
def take(String mediaType){
    [store_in: {path->
        this.path = path
        [on: { Closure closure->
            def code = closure.rehydrate(callbackHandler, null, null)
            code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
            code.call()
        }]
    }]
}
```

But this arises the problem that no code completion is given in the IDE (I'm using IntelliJ). Is there any other way to force the order but maintaining the code completion of the IDE?

Comment: Since they're just property setters, not really, unless you return context-sensitive entities. E.g., `store_in` would return an instance of a `PictureTaker` rather than lumping everything into `CameraHandler`. I'd question whether the order is relevant here, actually.

Comment: Maybe it's not really relevant in this example, but I have to do some other DSLs in which would have more sense to force an order

Comment: The two easy choices are (a) maintain a state machine that enforces call order, e.g., you can't move from `store_in` to `take`, or (b) break up some of the classes. There are some inherent limitations to internal DSLs; sometimes it's better to write a minimal external DSL when context and semantics are very important.

Comment: I will take a look to the state machines. Do you have any example?

Comment: You should post your update as an answer.

Comment: I'll post and wait a day or two for other solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two easy choices are (a) maintain a state machine that enforces call order, e.g., you can't move from store_in to take, or (b) break up some of the classes.

**State Machines**

There are any number of ways the state machine itself can be implemented and its contexts enforced. The nutshell, simplistic is that in your setters you'd (a) examine the current state, (b) determine if the state you're entering is a valid transition, and (c) set the current ("next") state if the transition is allowed.

In your example, nutshell:

```
CameraHandler take(String mediaType) {
    // State enforcement elided...

    this.state     = TAKEN
    this.mediaType = mediaType
    this
}

CameraHandler store_in(String path) {
  if (this.state != TAKEN) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Media type must be specified")
  }

  this.state = STORED
  this.path  = path
  this
}
```

Again, there are a ton of ways the state machine can be implemented and enforced, e.g., you could have a map of states and possible following states, along with state handlers. This can be a pretty powerful tool.

**Breaking Up Functionality**

That's what Emmanuel suggested. Instead of returning a `CameraHandler` (e.g., the current instance) you'd return whatever class was allowed "next" in the chain of commands.

In your example:

```
take "picture" store_in "path" on { ... }
```

The `take` method would return a `StorageHandler` with a `store_in` method. The `StorageHandler` would return whatever implements the functionality inside the block. This has some advantages and disadvantages; you'd need to carry around enough state to make it work–but you need to keep track of that state *somewhere* in order to enforce your semantics. Breaking it into classes keeps them tight and easily-testable, whereas a state machine in a god class can deflect attention away from the underlying functionality.

**Inherent Internal DSL (iDSL) Limitations**

Internal DSLs (iDSL) are pretty cool; I enjoy them quite a bit. They have some limitations, though, and it's often the case that minimal external DSLs (eDSL) allow greater flexibility and implementation choices.

For example, you mentioned autocompletes: dynamic languages are already difficult to autocomplete, although breaking things into class *can* help with that. Whether or not it *would* depends on several factors, like whether or not the language's syntax rules provide unambiguous type resolution. (I haven't worked in Groovy much lately so I'm not sure.)

Minimal eDSLs can be implemented within IDEs, e.g., IntelliJ's MPS, and give you completion. There are web-based text editors that can help out with eDSLs with highlighting and completion. Some eDSLs and iDSLs can use the same syntax, too.

Ultimately it depends on your needs.

Comment: Fantastic explanation @dave-newton!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a Map of Closures, you can create custom classes for each step. For example, the *take()* method could return an object only containing the method *store_in()*, which would return a object with the only method being *on()*, and so on.

Comment: I think that this solution would introduce too much noise as one class for each method can become a bit difficult to maintain, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, but it will enforce order of the dsl and maintain IDE code completion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way that seems to work. If the return of the method is a map of closures, you can call the methods in the given order. For example:

```
def take(String mediaType){
    [store_in: {path->
        this.path = path
        [on: { Closure closure->
            def code = closure.rehydrate(callbackHandler, null, null)
            code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
            code.call()
        }]
    }]
}
```

But this arises the problem that no code completion is given in the IDE...

Comment: Internal DSLs usually have code completion issues, though; because they're inherently dynamic it's difficult for the IDE's parsing engine to figure out what can "come next". The state machine would have the same issue. That's one reason why minimal external DSLs (e.g., IntelliJ's solution, or plain old editors that support syntax highlighting, or minimal custom editors) can sometimes be a better choice.